# Many-to-many relationship and QGIS Forms

Tags: qgis, postgresql, many-to-many

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database with a base table (`Pois_points`) and two subtables which constitute a many-to-many relationship with the base table, as you can see on the picture below (click on Many to many relationships).

I want to build a QGIS form that depicts this relationship between the tables when adding and editing items. I have seen examples of a one-to-many relationship in QGIS, which is relatively easy. But many-to-many is not documented or maybe not possible at all?

[image: Many to many relationships]

Comment: Could you please add QGIS version & OS?

Comment: I'm sorry: QGis version 2.16.1, installed on Windows 10, 64bits

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having a bit of bad design in your database, you can create the relation between your Pois_points and History tables using the relational value widget and check "allow multiple selections". You'll have to create a new column in your Pois_points table in which foreign keys will be stored as varchar arrays.

If you want a clean N:M relationship you can try [this solution](https://medspx.fr/blog/Qgis/better_qgis_forms_part_three/) but you'll have to write some Python.

Since this [pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/2522) it should now be possible to create N:M relationship in QGIS easily. Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#n-m-relation).

Unfortunately I can't make it working so I opened a [ticket](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16446).

[image: N:M relationship configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a relationship for poi-pos and the ps-points-history table, then a relationship for the history table and pos-points-history table.

Comment: The relationships themselves are allready defined on the database level. What I am looking for is how to make a QGIS form of the attributes of each feature displayed in QGIS, where for instance the selected history names are viewable and where you can change the selection based of a dropdown list of available history names. If its a one-to-many relationship, that's not so difficult, if it's a many-to-many then I haven't seen any documented working example. I have tried on my own, but without any satisfying result.

Comment: Yeh what I'm saying is in QGIS you define both relationships separately, then set up the one form and you should be right. From your question I assume you can already setup a relationship in QGIS and set up the forms, if not I can give you help on tha